# Glob to match subdirectories

Tags: bash, osx, wildcards

Hopefully I am not the only one that finds globs to misbehavior. If you'd asked me an hour ago, I would have been 99% confident that

```
test/src/**/*.js
```

would match all .js files in src and all subdirectories of src..but I am on MacOS and using Bash 3.2.57, and it's not matching more than one file.

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Your shell might be wrong. First enter `zsh` and then do your globbing. SCNR

Comment: Haha :) i am stuck on bash for now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash 3.2 doesn't support globstar:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
```

Without `shopt -s globstar`, `**` is just a plain non-recursive glob.

The bash [NEWS](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) page says:

> This is a terse description of the new features added to bash-4.0 since
>   the release of bash-3.2.  As always, the manual page (doc/bash.1) is
>   the place to look for complete descriptions.
>
> 1. New Features in Bash
>
>    [...]
>
>    w.  There is a new shell option: `globstar`.  When enabled, the
>      globbing code
>      treats `**` specially -- it matches all directories (and files within
>      them, when appropriate) recursively.

You'll need to update your bash to at least 4.0 (probably install one from homebrew), or use `find`.

Comment: is the `shopt` builtin specific to bash only, but the `set` builtin is part of posix, i.e. all "bourne" shells have it?

Comment: I don't know about other shells, but yes, `shopt` is not POSIX and `set` is.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find` to do this instead. For example:

```
find ./test/src -type f -name \*.js
```

If you want to limit to only 2 directories deep:

```
find ./test/src -maxdepth 2 -type f -name \*.js
```