# feh warns on text files

Tags: images, error-handling, feh

How do I get rid of these warnings from `feh`? I am trying to run a slideshow using images in a directory. Why is `feh` trying to open text files in that directory?

```
feh WARNING: images/temp.txt - No Imlib2 loader for that file format
```

Command used:

```
feh -FxYzZ -D 15  images
```

Is there a way to tell `feh` only to look at certain file extensions?

Comment: Remove the non-image files from the `images` folder?

Comment: Or make guesses as to the file type with `file(1)` first and then try to either include images or exclude not-images.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to add `-q` option (aka `--quiet`) to suppress non-fatal errors for failed loads:

```
feh -qFxYzZ -D 15  images
```

And you may always redirect stderr to `/dev/null` (`feh ... 2>/dev/null`), but that would be rather ugly solution as you could miss important errors.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is `feh` trying to open text files in that directory?

Per [`man feh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/feh.1.html), "By default (unless arguments or a filelist are specified) **feh** displays all files in the current directory."

> How do I get rid of these warnings from `feh`?
>
> ```
> feh WARNING: images/temp.txt - No Imlib2 loader for that file format
> ```

You have at least two alternatives:

1. use **feh**'s `-q` (or `--quiet`) option;
2. pass a list of image files to **feh**. You can do this any of several ways, e.g.:

   - place the list into a file and use **feh**'s `-f` (or `--filelist`) option: `feh -f imagelist.txt`
   - use traditional globbing: `feh *.jp*g`
   - pipe a list of files to **feh** from **find** or similar (which will allow you to include files from subdirectories): `find . -iname '*.jp*g' | feh -f -`
   - use [globstar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379192) globbing (which will likewise allow you to include files from subdirectories): `feh **/*.jp*g`

> Is there a way to tell `feh` only to look at certain file extensions?

The approaches listed under point 2 above all achieve this :)

Answer (score 1):

`feh` expects to find only image files in the directory.  If there are non-image files in there, it will fail with the diagnostic message that you describe.

You may run `feh` with `-u` or `--unloadable` to get a list of files that it can't load. You may also specify a text file with image filenames to display using `-f` or `--filelist`.

For further information, see the `feh` manual on your system.